# The references are not compiled in a latex file with only a table

Tags: tables, natbib

I have a latex file as follows. I have `document.bib`, `natbib.bst`, and `natbib.sty` in the same directory. The latex file compiles, when I use `pdflatex` command, but the references appear in from of `?`

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lscape}
\bibliographystyle{plos2015}
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{bmpsize} 
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c | p{4cm}  |p{8cm}|} % centered columns (4 columns)
\caption{The list of cell line specific keywords}
\label{cell line-specific terms Table}\\
\hline
Tissue & keyword & definition \\ \hline
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{B}} & ne 
nal & n.  \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & gluttac & Glu (\citet{Mel2000}, \citet{RiePlaMic2003}).   \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & olyte &  Oles (also k (\citet{SchWilDar2005}). \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & ite &  De.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 &  syc &  Synap (\citet{Lyn2004}).  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& denus& ital coding. \\
 \cline{2-3} 
 & behaf left &  Important f  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & bin  &  in.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & micre &  miap   \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & spi &  T ner  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & gamutyric & Gamma-.   \\  \cline{2-3} 
 &  ceral, cerem & n  (\citet{WolRapSch2009}) \\  \cline{2-3}
 & prepulse inhibition & \\  \cline{2-3}
 & Myein&Myen shea. \\  \cline{2-3} 
  & ascyte & Asn (\citet{PieVarSyk2004})  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & olfactolb & Olfacto (\citet{SobPraDes1998}). \\  \cline{2-3} 
& eph rtor & -  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& dne & Dopac(\citet{MarBer1979}),  (\citet{SalBenLar2011}), and abpain (\citet{ScoHeiKoe2006})  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& axonogenesis, axon & -   \\  \cline{2-3} 
&  myelion & Mye.   \\  \cline{2-3} 
& ostblast  & -   \\  

 \hline 

 \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Mle}}  & samere  &  Muscleomere.   \\ \cline{2-3} 
   &  muscle, muscular & - \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &  MPK & MAPK (mie (\citet{KerTamBen2006}  \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &  myobl& tes.   \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &  crec process & Seatine w  (\citet{FitShi1966}).   \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &glycogen&\\ \cline{2-3} 
 &collagen &\\
   \hline 

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{heell}}  & T cell & -   \\ \cline{2-3} 
    &  maage & Maaghages.  \\ \cline{2-3} 
     & MH II &  MH  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& MyD88 & -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& tolor & To-lik (\citet{ReyMarChu2012}).  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& MHss I&MHof the ody. Their funune .\\  \cline{2-3} 
& tumtor(TNF)& Most mand s\\ 

\hline

\multirow{27}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Immtem}}
& phcytosis& Phas are  that can. \\ \cline{2-3} 
& erocytes& -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& Bll& -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& porphin& One of the knd cells.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
&heme  process& Heme marrow. \\ \cline{2-3} 
& toll-lior& Toll-lders.   \\ \cline{2-3}

& boneation & \\ \cline{2-3}
& defense&\\ \cline{2-3}
& lipoharide&Lipopolystem \citet{Hof2003}.\\ \cline{2-3}
&phagosome&In y, a phagosome isytosis\\ \cline{2-3}
& interost&-\\ \cline{2-3}
& immsponse&-\\ \cline{2-3}
&antigen&In immunology, an antig \\ \cline{2-3}
& Interferons&Interferons (IFNs) are ls.\\ \cline{2-3}
& 
Superoxide&d\citet{MarZivNev2003}. \\ \cline{2-3}
&  df&s (\citet{Gun2007}, \citet{Bel1983}).\\ \cline{2-3}
&  f&f\citet{HicKub2009}\\ \cline{2-3}
& v& b\\ \cline{2-3}

 &c & Chemoion (\citet{Lus2001}, \citet{MatHogLuk2000}, \citet{TauOpp1994})\\ \cline{2-3}
& Macres&Maages stimul \citet{GalMat2001}.\\ \cline{2-3}
& Dendrs &Dendvers. \\ \cline{2-3}
&inteukin&Intens s ().\\ \cline{2-3}
&cytokine&They are partic \citet{Ale2002;}.\\ \cline{2-3}
& acute-ph response&Pos.\\ \cline{2-3} 
&dt&\\ \cline{2-3} 
&d&Tc.\\ \cline{2-3} 
&chemotactic&\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{hrt}}  & adrent & adrenontrtions   \\ \cline{2-3} 
& heart & -  \\ \cline{2-3} 

& cardiac & -   \\ 
  \hline 

\end{longtable}


\bibliography{document}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

I have the file `plos2015.bst` for `bibliographystyle`
I get the following error for every reference in the command line as I compile:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `TauOpp1994' on page 1 undefined on input line 87.
```

I use the following to compile:

```
latex temp
bibtex document
latex temp
latex temp
latex temp


dvipdf temp.dvi
okular temp.dvi &
```

where, `temp` is the `tex` file, and `document` is the `bib` file.

In the `document.blg` file, I see the following:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (Web2C 7.5.6)
The top-level auxiliary file: document.aux
The style file: natbib.bst
Database file #1: document.bib.bib
You've used 40 entries,
            2378 wiz_defined-function locations,
            856 strings with 20470 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 25797 in all, are:
= -- 2055
> -- 2284
< -- 8
+ -- 717
- -- 708
* -- 2843
:= -- 4685
add.period$ -- 192
call.type$ -- 40
change.case$ -- 248
chr.to.int$ -- 39
cite$ -- 40
duplicate$ -- 783
empty$ -- 1361
format.name$ -- 764
if$ -- 4862
int.to.chr$ -- 2
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 40
newline$ -- 203
num.names$ -- 160
pop$ -- 235
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 248
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 496
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 1562
swap$ -- 151
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 360
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 189
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 521
```

---

**EDIT: The Error looks like this.**

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no bibliography style called `natbib.bst`, at least not on the CTAN. If you check the file `\jobname.blg` (where `\jobname` is the name of your main tex file), you will probably find an error message about BibTeX not being able to locate `natbib.bst`. You should replace the instruction `\bibliographystyle{natbib}` with `\usepackage{natbib}` and, separately, specify a suitable bibliography style.

Comment: The most likely explanation for there being no `blg` file would be that BibTeX wasn't run.

Comment: Without knowledge of the contents of the file `documents.bib`, it's not exactly easy to give meaningful advice.

Comment: If I remember correctly: This is a ~bug in natbib, references that arent fully cited ( \cite ) have problems. If it this problem then you could use a \nocite to fix this, so say \nocite{all your keys} somewhere in the document so that all references are cited

Comment: thanks for your time. Please have a look here. I uploaded the file. http://expirebox.com/download/4348692d17faa6bdf22972d515f1a2a1.html

Comment: @Mico I dont think any thing is wrong with bib file, because I use the same file in my article itself, and the references are correctly compiled/shown.

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to the bib file. I didn't say there was anything wrong with the bib file, by they way. I was only remarking that without it, it wasn't likely that meaningful and specific advice might be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's something unusual about the way the bibliography style `plos2015` interacts with LaTeX and natbib. At any rate, if you replace the 23 instances of `\citet` with `\cite`, the document you posted appears to compile without further errors.

Comment: Do you see ? marks in the resulting pdf? I still see them, after replacing citet to cite.

Comment: @Pegah - No, I have no unwanted ? marks in the pdf file after (a) changing all instances of `\citet` to `\cite` and (b) running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Comment: Could you upload the tex file please? I have no idea why it works on your system.

Comment: @Pegah -- All I did with your tex file was to (a) change all 23 instances of `\citet` to `\cite`, (b) remove the command that loads the `vector` package since it's not installed on my system (MacOSX 10.10, MacTeX2015), and (c) insert the instruction `\usepackage{url}` since `\url` occurs several times in the bib file.

Comment: I don't understand why we don't get the same results. I have uploaded my tex file here. I would really appreciate if you have a look at it. I have this problem with this file since months and really don't know what to do with it. http://expirebox.com/download/2223e0d454ef85c1137fee7f5ecbbff7.html

Comment: to compile I use the following: latex temp
bibtex document
latex temp
latex temp
latex temp


dvipdf temp.dvi
okular temp.dvi &

Comment: @Pegah - Thanks for providing a link to your pdf file. If I move the instruction `\usepackage{url}` from its location in your file to immediately after the loading of `graphicx`, the question marks go away. No idea why this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer. I made the change you mentioned above as well, still no effect. I think You have something that I do not have. In the directory where I compile, I have, document.bib, plos2015.bst, natbib.sty, temp.tex. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @Pegah - The file `natbib.sty` shouldn't have to be in the same directory with `\jobname.tex`.  What happens if you remove (or rename) the copy of `natbib.sty` and recompile?

Comment: After so much struggle, just by chance, I changed the name of the bib file to the name of the supplement, and it at last compiled. Thanks for your time and help.